# Select text on focus when using react-final-form

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

I need to be able to handle onFocus events so I can select the text when using react-final-form. I tried searching through the docs, but wasn't able to find any resources on that topic. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a feature that react-final-form provides. You'll have to handle the `onFocus` event yourself to do that.

It's not that hard, though.

[image: Edit React Final Form - Simple Example]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ya, I guess I was looking for a generic onFocus handler of some sorts, but it might not even make any sense anyway. So I ended up extending an Input component. Not that hard, just as you said.